# Can't connect to VPN in network manager for KDE in Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, kde, vpn, openvpn

I have nordvpn and have used the openvpn config files on their website for a while on gnome and it has worked perfectly. I switched to KDE and in the network manager I can import vpn settings from the config file the same as in gnome and enter my username and password, but when I press the connect button nothing happens. It doesn't give any error it just does nothing.

[Here is the button I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SCbK.png)

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that you have all the required packages like `network-manager-openvpn` (or in my case `network-manager-openconnect`) or some other packages in `apt search networkmanager` or `apt search network-manager`. Unfortunately, when these packages are missing, it does not display any error message -- it just "does nothing"

Comment: Installing the `network-manager-openconnect` package with `sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect` worked for me on KDE Neon.

Answer (score 9):

I solved on Ubuntu 22 with this command:

`sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn`

Answer (score 1):

This command

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-l2tp
```

works for me on Ubuntu 20.04
I was getting

> Missing VPN plugin error

when connecting to l2tp on Mikrotik router.